# Can "potion" be uncountable?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, nouns, uncountable-nouns

I don't understand why all dictionaries say "**potion**" is countable.

That is we can not say "**he drank some potion**".

Normally, a witch boils/makes a pot of potion. And then she just drinks some potion not a potion.

It is so hard to express idea if "**potion**" is not uncountable.

But, google book has a lot of results ["drink some potion"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22drink%20some%20potion%22)

Comment: It can be either, like "liquid". You can pour some liquid, and water is a liquid. But I'm not sure why the dictionary doesn't say this.

Comment: 'Drink some of the potion' or Drink some of a potion' are both better grammar than 'drink some potion. In both of these you are drinking part of a singular potion. 'Drink some potions' means you are drinking more than one (countable) potions. In all of these cases the phrases are usually about some already discussed (singular or countable) potion or potions.

Comment: Without context, it's possible "some potion" means "a random potion", rather than referring to "potion" in an uncountable way.

Comment: He would be hard pressed to drink **two potions**.  Right? A witch makes a potion, not a "pot of it", usually. She may, however, make it **in a pot**.//drink some coffee versus drink two coffees, OK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We usually refer to *a potion* in the sense of a particular mixture made up by someone, rather than a generic substance like milk or wine. So you could say 'The witch drank some of the potion she had made'. (Of course, we can also say *a wine* to refer to a particular kind.)

It's possible that some of the quotations found by Google are using 'some potion' to mean 'an unspecified potion' rather than 'a small quantity'. In some cases, it's part of a phrase like 'some potion ingredients' or 'some potion vials' (ingredients or containers for a potion) - or it can mean 'some (of the previously mentioned) potion'. So it's not correct that we *cannot* say 'he drank some potion', but the word is usually thought of as countable.

Comment: In Ngram, "some potion" is much more common than "some of the potion" https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=some+potion%2Csome+of+the+potion&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t4%3B%2Csome%20potion%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsome%20potion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSome%20potion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csome%20of%20the%20potion%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Csome%20potion%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsome%20potion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSome%20potion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csome%20of%20the%20potion%3B%2Cc0

Comment: See the additions to my answer.

Comment: If the witch or wizard had a clumsy accident, I might well say 'I've got potion all over my shirt".